# Cannot spawn a model in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to spawn a robot model in Gazebo after successfully converted from .xacro to .urdf. But when I tried to spawn the robot with terminal command, it gave me this error

```
nuttaworn@nuttaworn-Lenovo-Z50-70:~/valkyrie_ws/src/val_description/model/robots$ rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file 'rospack find val_description'/model/robots/valkyrie_sim.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model valkyrie
spawn_model script started
[INFO] [WallTime: 1477593321.260120] [0.000000] Loading model xml from file
Error: file does not exist rospack find val_description/model/robots/valkyrie_sim.urdf
```

I checked the path to the urdf file and it's the exact path. I tried finding the package with `rospack` and it located the package without any problem. Can somebody point out what I missed? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246611/cannot-spawn-a-model-in-gazebo/) by [nsujumnong](https://answers.ros.org/users/28361/nsujumnong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order for your shell to run a command and use it's output as part of the command for the shell, you need to use backticks (`), not regular quotes ('). So your command line should probably be:

```
rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file `rospack find val_description`/model/robots/valkyrie_sim.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model valkyrie
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nsujumnong](https://answers.ros.org/users/28361/nsujumnong/) on 2016-10-27**:
ahh.... that makes more sense. it works now. thank you so much